# Copy specific contact information in outlook for phone

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, android

I'm helping out a guy setting up his phone. He's got a lot of contacts in his personal file in Outlook that he'd like to get on his phone…however he's got extensive notes for each contact that he does not want to transfer—he just wants emails and phone numbers.

He just set up a hosted exchange account with godaddy so he can copy the contacts to that hosted account in Outlook, but I'm not familiar enough with Outlook to know if there's a way to copy just specific information (phone numbers and emails) but not others (Notes, etc)

A way to do this from inside Outlook would be best, though I'd be open to exporting to CSV, deleting and reimporting.

(Phone is Android 2.2, for your reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook can easily export/import contacts using CSV format. You did not specify your Outlook version, but in Outlook 2010 it can be done using File -> Options -> Advanced -> Export button.
You will be able to map any contact fields.

Comment: Thanks. I exported to CSV and manually deleted the Notes, then reimported--also changed mapping so notes column didn't get mapped, to be double-sure. Kludgy, but appears to be the accepted method.